# There are three tags... for rpi gpio

Tags: discussion

`rpi.gpio` , `pigpio` and `pi-gpio` all appear to be the same tag, they should be merged.

rpi.gpio refers to the package name of a Python module for accessing the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins. The module allows GPIO...

pigpio, a library for accessing GPIO pins as well as other functions including I2C. pigpio has a client-server architecture ,

pi-gpio For general questions about the GPIO pins, do not use this tag; use [gpio]. This tag is for the npm (node.js package manager)

If one of these tags is not the same, then it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

These tags are distinct:

- [rpi.gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpi.gpio) refers to a Python package called [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/). Tag description: *rpi.gpio refers to the package name of a Python module for accessing the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins.*
- [pigpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigpio) refers to a **different** Python package called [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/). Tag description: *pigpio is a library for accessing GPIO pins as well as other functions including I2C. pigpio has a client-server architecture , which enables you to remotely control GPIO pins.*
- [pi-gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-gpio) is for a module in Node.js, called `pi-pgio`. Tag description: *This tag is for the npm (node.js package manager) module for controlling the GPIO pins on the Pi using JavaScript. It is unrelated to the pigpio C/Python library.*

Merging these tags wouldn't make sense as they are for different projects. Perhaps it'd be helpful to edit the tag excerpts (anyone can suggest an edit to be reviewed) if there is any confusion. I hope this clarifies the meanings of the different tags.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, if you click through from the tag page listing questions via **"Learn more..."** you will find an additional page of just information, who's URL has an `/info` suffix.

All three of those (now) have a link to an official homepage which makes fairly clear the difference between them.  In addition I've added this to each:

---

### Please Note!

If you are not aware, there are a number of different pieces of software that serve a similar fundamental purpose (controlling the Raspberry Pi GPIO pins) and are independent of one another.  Not surprisingly, they also all use spins on combining "rpi" and "gpio" in their name.  Each has a separate tag and questions about their use should use that specific tag.  This is documented here to prevent confusion.

- The `pi-gpio` node.js (javascript) library: Tag [pi-gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-gpio)
- The `pigpio` library, written in C but with ports to python and other languages: Tag [pigpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigpio)
- The `RPi.GPIO` module for python: Tag [rpi.gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpi.gpio)

This isn't intented as an exhaustive list of such software, just the three most prone to confusion here due to the similar names perhaps made more similiar by restrictions on tag labels (all lower case, etc).

---

But with the list re-arranged to put the current on on top annotated, **"The page you are on now is for..."**.